# how to delete a row from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 matrices: matrix_1 and matrix_2

```
matrix_1 = np.array[[1,2,3],[4,N,6],[7,8,9],[N ,1,2]]

matrix_2 = np.array[[2,4,5],[3,6,7],[3,6,8],[1,3,6]]
```

and i want it to delete the row that contains the N in it and also delete the corresponding row of matrix_2

e.g. in `matrix_1` i want it to delete the row `[4,N,6]` and also delete `[3,6,7]` #the corresponding row in matrix 2
i want it to do that for all the rows containing N

```
    result = []
    def testanswer(matrix_1,matrix_2):
        for i in range(len(matrix_1)):
            answer = matrix_1[i,1]*matrix_1[i,2]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(matrix_1[i,0]))
            answer2 = matrix_2[i,1]*matrix_2[i,2]*np.cos(np.deg2rad(matrix_2[i,0])) 
            result.append([answer,answer2])
        return result
```

Comment: FWIW, by "matrix" here, although you may be using it in your application as a matrix, it is a *Numpy array* so any documentation you can find on Numpy will help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # Supose that N = -1
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,-1,6],[7,8,9],[-1 ,1,2]])
>>> b = b = np.array([[2,4,5],[3,6,7],[3,6,8],[1,3,6]])
>>> keep_idx = np.all(a != -1, axis=1)
>>> a[keep_idx]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b[keep_idx]
array([[2, 4, 5],
       [3, 6, 8]])
```